# getElementById.elements not picking up label

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Code first:

```
function loopForm() {

var e = document.getElementById("form1").elements;

for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
  alert('this is ' + e[i].ID + ' of type' + e[i].type);
}
```

I have the above code sitting in a .js, which is called from a .aspx with dynamic created controls like textbox, dropdownlist, checkbox and labels, in Server side, in a form called form1.  My question is,

> the code is picking up all the controls' ID and types, **except
>   labels** and  I am looking for a way to manipulate with label (change
>   style.display, color, etc)

I have attempted with JQuery code such as:

```
$("#form1 label").each(function() {  //I used "div", "label" and all sort
alert('hi');
});
```

and does not work.  Please note that while document.getElementById might work, the controls exist on the page differ from everytime so it cannot be hardcoded.

EDIT: Here's how label is added to the .aspx (in my codebehind):

```
private Label lbl = new Label();
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl NewDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");  
NewDiv1.Controls.Add(lbl);
form1.Controls.Add(NewDiv);
```

Comment: Please define 'label' and/or show us the HTML and point out exactly which element you don't get.

Comment: `.elements` picks up form controls. `label`s aren't form controls - they hold no data, don't cause form submission, and aren't part of the data submitted *with* the form. Example, here, where only the `input` is returned, not the `label` next to it. http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/RWOVrv

Comment: from the answers and comments here I am sure I have misunderstood how label is being treated.  @admiraalit the label will not be showing on the html unless you "view source" after the page/form is loaded.

Comment: @PaulRoub thx as i mentioned  I am sure I have misunderstood how label is being treated.   I am looking for a way on how to individually change each label's style (i.e. change a label's style.display to 'inline' when a textbox is empty)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you talk about `labels`, I suspect you are referring to ASP.NET server controls, such as `asp:Label`. If that is the case, then you're really looking for `<span>` tags, as ASP.NET turns a `<asp:Label>` into an html `<span>`.

And if you want to refer to these elements by their Id, you will notice that ASP.NET does not use the same Id on the client side as what you defined on the server side.

However, there is a workaround. If you want the client Id to be the same as the server id, set the following property on your server control: `ClientIdMode="Static".`

For example, in your .aspx page you have this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Id="lblName"></asp:Label>
```

It will generate something like this in the html:

```
<span id="someservergeneratedid_lblName"></span>
```

If you want to control the id yourself, you can do this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" ClientIdMode="static"></asp:Label>
```

And that will generate this in html:

```
<span id="lblName"></span>
```

Comment: "And if you want to refer to these elements by their Id, you will notice that ASP.NET does not use the same Id on the client side as what you defined on the server side."  - @OliverDeMeulder would you please elaborate on this?  I do assign ID on the server side and it's showing with the code except labels.  Also, 'ClientIdMode="Static" would be included on the aspx or?

Comment: @OliverDeMeulder thanks for the update, however the label is added in codebehind (server side after a postback) and there is no such thing like <asp:Label...> tag exists

Comment: @Alex How is the label added in Codebehind?

Comment: Using Div generated as below: System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl NewDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");

then, newDiv.Controls.Add(lbl); where lbl is a declared as Label variable.

then, form1.Controls.Add(newDiv) to be included in the form

Comment: So, then, before that call set lbl.ClientIdMode = "Static";

Comment: I am not sure how I address this to you, it's like if you go document.getElementById("Department_errlbl").style.display = 'inline' / 'none', I can make the label visible / invisible.  However, the label is not guaranteed to be load, depends on the form.  So unless I check for every label's ID on each page load, I do not know how it can be done.  Also, I am not sure if the label's ID is the problem here

Comment: Then you should set a class for these labels. In your codebehind lbl.CssClass = "someclass"; and in JavaScript use getElementsByClass

Comment: There after a couple attempts I finally got it working with Class.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

> the code is picking up all the controls' ID and types, except labels

That's normal. The elements collection is only supposed to contain the form controls (and fieldsets for some reason). Labels aren't supposed to be in there.

> ```
> $("div").each(function() { alert($(this).val()); });
> ```

Div and label elements don't have values, so that shouldn't work.

You can select HTML label elements easily enough though:

```js
jQuery("#form1 label").each(function () {
    jQuery("body").append("<p>Appending because alert is disabled in snippets</p>");
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <label>Hello
    <input name="hello" value="world">
  </label>
  <label>Goodbye
    <input name="hello" value="world">
  </label>
</form>
```

As Olivier points out though, make sure your HTML looks how you expect and that ASP.NET is generating the elements you are looking for with the correct types.

Comment: thanks but with a different label loaded each time, and changing those individually (i.e. display error label when textbox is empty) cannot be done as how your answer setup?

Comment: @Alex — There's nothing stopping you using `each`. I just didn't because it wasn't needed to solve the problem that you stated in the question.

Comment: I have tried using $("#form1 label").each and it simply don't do anything (I just use alert('hi') instead of val()).  Please see my answer update in a min, thanks

Comment: @Alex — Changed the answer to use `each`. It works fine.

Comment: I think the problem is, there will be no <label> tag in the .aspx as it is added dynamically.  I have included more codes in my post

Comment: @Alex — If it's added dynamically then you just have to wait until it exists in the DOM before you try to change it.

Comment: … but that edit looks like server side code, which will run before the browser gets its hands on it and runs the JS on it. You need to, at I said at the end of my initial answer, **look at the HTML** that the browser gets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95748/discussion-between-alex-and-quentin).